# Random plot based on a specific random seed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, random

I would like to draw a set of random functions f(x) from point A to point B with a fixed random seed for each function. In other words, I would like to have functions which look the same each time I create the document, depending on their associated random seed.

So far, I have this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% Random path from A=(0,0) to B=(1,1) with seed #1 and color #2
\newcommand\randompath[2]{%
\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetseed{#1}}%
\addplot[#2,domain=0:1,samples=5,smooth] { x+rand*(x)*(1-x)};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]
    \randompath{1}{red}   % 1st function
    \randompath{1}{blue}  % 2nd function
    \randompath{1}{green} % 3rd function
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However, the three functions are not identical and change their shape on recreation. Therefore, the `\pgfmathsetseed` does not seem to work as intended?

**How can I achieve it that for a chosen seed number, the drawn `\randompath` function looks alway the same?**

Comment: Everything that's put in `\pgfextra` is executed in a separate group at the end of the `axis` environment (after all the plots have been calculated). Remove the `\pgfextra`, and you'll get three identical plots.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything that's put in `\pgfextra` is executed in a separate group at the end of the `axis` environment (after all the plots have been calculated). Remove the `\pgfextra`, and you'll get three identical plots.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
% Random path from A=(0,0) to B=(1,1) with seed #1 and color #2
\newcommand\randompath[2]{%
\pgfmathsetseed{#1}%
\addplot[#2,domain=0:1,samples=5,smooth] { x+rand*(x)*(1-x)};%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1]
    \randompath{1}{red, line width=8pt}   % 1st function
    \randompath{1}{blue, line width=4pt}  % 2nd function
    \randompath{1}{green, line width=1pt} % 3rd function
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```